# Erro HTTP 400 - "senderName invalid value" e "Must fit the patern: \d+.\d{2}2"

Tags: api

Estou tendo um problema para utilizar a api do PagSeguro v2.5.0.

Não estou sabendo criar o `sendbox`, `appID` e o a seguinte mensagem aparece quando mando os dados para o pagseguro:

```
[HTTP 400] - BAD_REQUEST 0 [11012] - senderName invalid value: Flávia1 [11029] 
           - Item amount invalid pattern: 2.5. Must fit the patern: \d+.\d{2}2 [11014] 
           - senderPhone invalid value: 8428.7471
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Para criar o appID vai em [https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/#rmcl](https://sandbox.pagseguro.uol.com.br/#rmcl), e para você ver os padroões de cada campo veja aqui [https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/api-de-pagamentos.html](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/api-de-pagamentos.html)

Comment: Faça títulos intuitivos por favor. "ajuda" todo mundo vem procurar aqui, o título deve ser útil para o entendimento da duvida. Obrigado!

Comment: Estes dados são de um banco de dados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem 3 erros na sua requisição:

O primeiro é o nome, o parâmetro esta sendo passado com um numero e o Pagseguro não aceita números no campo nome.

> senderName invalid value: Flávia1

O segundo é a quantidade, use virgula no lugar de ponto.

> Item amount invalid pattern: 2.5.

E o terceiro e ultimo é o telefone, não use pontos para separa-los, use hífen por exemplo: 1234-5678, não esqueça de passar o DDD também.

> senderPhone invalid value: 8428.7471